# In R, how to modify a column in a big dataframe based on rows in a small dataframe in an efficient way

Tags: r, performance, vectorization

I have a big dataframe called `big_set`:

```
                              hash is_in_small_set
1 6694662834f3d2942ec4c6af20ab0520              NA
2 265e53ecdb68d360890f9aa2d99c1ebe              NA
3 0b7cd1f468c88de7c8bf822a77d4dc4d              NA
# I have just printed the first three rows
```

and a small dataframe called `small_set`:

```
                              hash result
1 703a4f40f24afe5baadb03412514048f      b
2 d0cabfc660bf334524e758ef5c9774a4      a
3 265e53ecdb68d360890f9aa2d99c1ebe      c
```

I need to fill the column `big_set$is_in_small_set`:

```
                              hash is_in_small_set
1 6694662834f3d2942ec4c6af20ab0520           FALSE
2 265e53ecdb68d360890f9aa2d99c1ebe            TRUE
3 0b7cd1f468c88de7c8bf822a77d4dc4d           FALSE
```

I have a working solution with two nested for-loop but unfortunately it is too slow for my purposes where `nrow(big_set)` is about 10k and `nrow(small_set)` is about 100.

```
getRandString<-function(len=32) return(paste(sample(c(0:9,c('a','b','c','d','e','f')),len,replace=TRUE),collapse=''))

myfun <- function(big_sz)
{
    big_set <- data.frame(hash=replicate(big_sz,getRandString()))
    big_set$is_in_small_set <- NA

    small_sz <- big_sz/10
    small_set <- data.frame(hash=sample(big_set$hash,small_sz,replace=FALSE),result=sample(c("a","b","c"),small_sz,replace=TRUE))

    big_rows <- seq(1,big_sz)
    small_rows <- seq(1,small_sz)

    for (row_index_big in big_rows) {
        for (row_index_small in small_rows) {
            if (big_set[row_index_big,]$hash == small_set[row_index_small,]$hash) {
                big_set[row_index_big,]$is_in_small_set = TRUE
                break
            } else {
                big_set[row_index_big,]$is_in_small_set = FALSE
            }
        }
    }
}

system.time(myfun(10))
system.time(myfun(50))
system.time(myfun(75))
system.time(myfun(100))
system.time(myfun(200))
system.time(myfun(300))
```

The elapsed times:

```
   user  system elapsed 
   0.01    0.00    0.01 
   user  system elapsed 
   0.13    0.00    0.13 
   user  system elapsed 
   0.25    0.01    0.27 
   user  system elapsed 
   0.51    0.00    0.52 
   user  system elapsed 
   2.74    0.00    2.75 
   user  system elapsed 
   7.65    0.00    7.64
```

I have no idea on how to "vectorize" my code in order to speed it up.

Comment: Take a look at `%in%`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Ananda in the comments, the typical approach (in base R) would be to use the `%in%` function, i.e.:

```
big_set$is_in_small_set <- big_set$hash %in% small_set$hash
```

Or

```
big_set <- transform(big_set, is_in_small_set = hash %in% small_set$hash)
```

That should speed up your code significantly.